# Using Allauth and Redirecting to irrelevent URL

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-allauth

I'm using Django-Allauth, but when I upload my project in the server and click on the button to login via Google or Facebook, I redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:8001/accounts/google/login/callback/?state=*****`
instead of `http://example.com/accounts/google/login/callback/?state=*****`
I am newbie, so please help me in-depth step by step.

Answer (score 0):

In django admin, update your `Site` object's domain to your `server's ip` or your `domain name`.

Comment: Hi, No change! althought I changed it to the IP